# How can I get JSON result from Asp.Net Web Api 2 that looks like Google API response?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

Using ASP.net Web api 2 how can I response in google like manner:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

My model:

```
[DataContract]
public class ProductResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Status_Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ProductResponse GetAllProducts()
    {
        ProductResponse response = new ProductResponse();
        try
        {
            using (SQLServerWrapper sqlConn = new SQLServerWrapper())
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = sqlConn.PrepareCommand(Product.SQLSelect))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    response.Products = reader.Select<Product>(Product.FromDataReader).ToList();
                }
            }
            response.Status = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Status = "ERROR";
        }

        return response;
    }
```

All that works good. My question how can I switch reponse to JSON type that is readable by browsers?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"! And **please** work on the title - currently it is just a sequence of terms, which has inherently nothing to do with a title.

Comment: What do you mean by _"how can I switch reponse to JSON type that is readable by browsers"_? Browsers don't read JSON. What is the relation between your products and Google Maps' geocode output?

Comment: Just return result in json fortmat.

Comment: By saying "JSON type that is readable by browsers" I mean format that is correctly interpreted by browser AddOns like Firefox JSONView

Comment: Hello, have you solved this problem? How?

Comment: No, I haven;t solved it. Your answer is correct but obviously I meant to make the data available in JSON format by default, and response was interpreted correctly by the JSON parsers, browser plug-ins for example. JSON View (google reposponse is parsed correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, just request an answer in json :)

The type of the serialization is determined by an header in your request, or the absence of it.

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

By default asp.net web api can serialize eiter in xml or json.